# Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.6.21): No cached version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

My project in Kotlin(version:Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 ) can not run because of the "implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version". I have red more solutions in stack overflow but I could not find my answe I have attached my grade to this question.[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbHHg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJyBK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdiQO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPLRB.png)
thank you for your cooperation.

I want to solve my issue

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: I had the same issue the other day. Except with the jdk version 1_8 needing to be version 18. There could be a no cache because I think the version numbers are off. What jdk are you running?

Comment: My bad not 18 but 17

Comment: There is a lot of extensions that doesn't work anymore with 1_8. Kotlin extensions is one of them. I had to update the jdk to 17 and then change everything to view binding and my app worked again so I could update it on Google play

Comment: Are you offline / running Gradle in offline mode? Your second screenshot has a lot of "can't download" errors. (You can click the Gradle tab on the right of the window and look for the icon that's like =/= to see if you've put it in offline mode)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.